# Android Facebook SDK Login work only for my account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

This error is really annoying, I'm using Facebook SDK to allow users of my app to login with their FB accounts. Everything was perfect until I found out that I'm the only one who can login (My FB account is set as Developer in Facebook API), but testers can't login, not even the administrator can login.

I tried to put the APP in the production mode in the settings, but this didn't help.

I even went to sign the APK thinking this might help, but unluckily it didn't.

Here is my Logcat output:

```
 W/System.err: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error performing  query. [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login: Failed to resolve field.
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:167)
 W/System.err:     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:136)
W/System.err:     at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.myapp.version1.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:551)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3350)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3397)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your app is not published you should add users like testers in facebook + you should build apk with the same keystore, that's fingerprint was set on facebook application settings

Comment: I have testers, and they cannot login actually, and i didn't understand that part: "you should build apk with the same keystore", can you explane it further plz? cuz the keystore is for generating signed APKs and has nothing to do with Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It turned out to be just i didn't double check the app ID, i replaced it with the correct one and that fixed it.